# Compact Framework blocks access to COM Connection Points

Tags: c#, com, garbage-collection, compact-framework

I've been Googling a lot for this but no one seems to be talking about this issue.

I have a COM component written in C++ that exposes events ("connection points" in COM parlance). This component (a [map control](http://qscribble.blogspot.ca/2013/12/the-fastnav-mapping-component.html)) has been used reliably for several years by clients written in C++ and C# on Windows XP/7. It has also been used reliably for several years by clients written in C++ on Windows CE.

However, connection points are broken in the Compact Framework. There was one device on which they work, but on multiple other devices (different builds of WinCE), events spontaneously unsubscribe themselves!

```
MapControl _ctrl;
_IMapControlEvents_MouseEventEventHandler _temp;

public MapForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _ctrl = new MapControl();
    _ctrl.MouseEvent += (_temp = HandleMouseEvent);
    ...
}
...
```

At first `HandleMouseEvent()` is called by `_ctrl` for every mouse event, but as soon as a garbage collection occurs, the event is unsubscribed and `HandleMouseEvent()` is no longer called (I confirmed that the event is unsubscribed by editing the ATL code to print "Subscriber removed".)

Unfortunately it is impossible to re-subscribe. For example, if I use code like this:

```
_testTimer = new Timer();
_testTimer.Interval = 10000;
_testTimer.Enabled = true;
_testTimer.Tick += (s, e) => {
    _ctrl.MouseEvent -= _temp;
    _ctrl.MouseEvent += _temp;
};
```

This works as long as there is no garbage collection. But after the first GC, `_ctrl.MouseEvent -= _temp` and `_ctrl.MouseEvent += _temp` both throw `InvalidComObjectException` (0x80131527). You can still call methods on `_ctrl` but events cannot be used.

So, does anyone know a workaround for this issue? (Is anyone else even having this issue?)

**Version**: \Windows\cgacutil.exe reports Compact Framework [3.5.11125.0]

Comment: Sounds ugly and I have no solution, but you might add in the version of the CF you're testing with, down to the revision number.  It might matter (and it might not).

Comment: OK. Actually what's really super ugly is what happens if I attempt to use a COM object in a Compact Framework 2.0 program on our main target device (Ranger 4). I can instantiate and use a COM object, no problem, but after creating a COM object (even if I don't do anything with it), hundreds or thousands of different APIs in the BCL start throwing `NotSupportedException` whenever they are called.  The "Fatal Error" dialog displayed by CF itself throws `NotSupportedException` when you click Quit, causing another dialog, so the process won't exit. Solution: build for .NET CF 3.5 instead of 2.0.

Comment: yeah, COM interop in 2.0 was touchy at best